# Автоматический запуск автотестов

Tags: selenium, тестирование, test-automation, автоматизация

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы автотесты, которые предназначены для тестирования интерфейса (python+selenium, cypress), запускались сами, между определёнными интервалами, при том, что мне запрещено использовать Jenkins, Ansible. Чтобы автотесты прогонялись независимо от проекта?

Comment: А куда должны попадать результаты прогонов? Если, например, на почту - то делаем скрипт, который это прогоняет, результат кидает на почту. И вешаем это на крон. `мне запрещено использовать Jenkins, Ansible` - а еще есть Gitlab, который можно поднять локально, например.